ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in AnyLogic Road Traffic Library - Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
I'm working on a road traffic simulation in AnyLogic where a set of vehicles randomly visit multiple stop lines and then proceed to their next destination. However, I'm encountering the following error during the simulation:
Exception during discrete event execution:
Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
at com.anylogic.libraries.road.ay.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.road.ay.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.road.am.a(Unknown Source)
...

Context:
I am not using the shapefile feature. All roads and intersections were manually created and scaled.
The error seems to be related to the road network and car agents.
The vehicles follow a path that leads them to different stop lines, and then they move on to the next stop line or destination.
My Question:
What could be the root cause of this error, and how can I resolve it? Could it be related to how the vehicles interact with the road network or stop lines? Any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated!
I suspect that the issue might be with one of the roads in the network, but I haven't been able to pinpoint it.

The root cause is: some code tries to access an array element that doesn't exist. But that problem is probably hundreds of layers deep into that software. Basically it is impossible to "remote" debug something like this. But please understand: this community is for specific technical questions, it is not intended to assist you debugging such problems. Meaning: most likely your question will get closed, because nobody here can really help you with it.

Having said that, the approach you should try: "minimize" your problem. Meaning: if possible, reduce it to the smallest "input data set" that leads to the problem. But given the context that you provide here, that sounds really difficult. Also note: AnyLogic is a commercial product, isn't it?! So your first stop should be their support desk.

Thank you for your response. I understand the complexity involved, but I'm looking for guidance on how to debug this issue effectively. Could you suggest any methods or tools I might use to identify the specific part of the intersection or road network that is causing the problem? Your insights would be greatly appreciated!

As @GhostCat has suggested, the best way to debug this issue is to minimize your problem. I'd suggest first checking on the console if there is some line in your own code which is causing the bug - we cannot really know this without any more information from your model. Then, if this is not related to any of your code and due to AnyLogic library, minimize your problem: start with just maybe two roads and an intersection, and gradually and step-wise increase your problem until you can find what is causing the issue.

this error is the same as "list index out of range" - your list's (or whatever it could be) size is shorter than 3
